# How can I make an instance return the String of a field directly in Java as I could do in Python with __radd__?

Tags: java, python, string, field, instance

In Python, if I wanted an instance to return a string of a field directly, I could do something like this:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
        self.__repr__ = self.__str__

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other + self.field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.field

x = X("example.")
print("This is an " + x)
```

In Java, I don't know how I would do it...

```
public class X {

    public String field;

    public X(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        X x = new X("example.");
        System.out.println("This is an " + x.field); // Just x would return the address of the object in memory.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could `Override` `toString` in `X` with something like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return field;
}
```

Then you could use

```
System.out.println("This is an " + x);
```

which would implicitly call `toString` (e.g. is equivalent to)

```
System.out.println("This is an " + x.toString());
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `toString()` method:

```
public class X { 
    public String field; 

    public X(String field) { 
        this.field = field; 
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.field;
    }
}
```